# Database first automatic class causes CA2214: Do not call overridable methods in constructors

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Auto generated class by EntityFramework 6.1:

```
public partial class STUDENT
{
    public STUDENT()
    {
        this.STUDENT_GROUPS = new HashSet<STUDENT_GROUPS>();
    }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int PERSON { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<STUDENT_GROUPS> STUDENT_GROUPS { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And STUDENT_GROUPS:

```
public partial class STUDENT_GROUPS
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int GROUPS_GRP { get; set; }
    public int STUDENT { get; set; }

    public virtual STUDENT STUDENT1 { get; set; }
    public virtual GROUPS_GRP GROUPS_GRP1 { get; set; }
}
```

Throws a CA2214: Do not call overridable methods in constructors, but since this is an autogenerated code, I think I am not supposed to change it, how should i approach this scenario?
Thanks in advance

Comment: How can it be code first if something else is generating the code?

Comment: Also, that's obviously not the entire code for the class, since we can't see the `STUDENT_GROUPS` property - where is that defined?

Comment: @DavidG actually EntityFramework generated the classes from the existing database.

Comment: @Juanito You have given us the `STUDENT_GROUPS` class which isn't what was asked for. @Damien asked for the property which exists in the other half of the `STUDENT` partial class.

Comment: @DavidG you are right, my mistake

Comment: You can add `[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]` on the model class' constructor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you have posted is not throwing an error, it is just violating a code analysis rule and will work fine. The generated code is correct and by design to allow for lazy loading. You should suppress that warning for those files.

Comment: I am also having this issue and suppressing the warning is not an option because the business mandate is that there can be no critical warnings in FxCop. Is there another solution?

Comment: Sorry I didn't find any solution to this, what I do is to configure the project with "Microsoft Minimum Recommended Rules", i did this because those classes are code generated by the entity framework, here some explanation about the code analysis http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2010/04/27/static-code-analysis-configuration.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can ignore the warning, but if you want to avoid it, you can make manually a private field for each virtual property (and setter/getter manually too). Then, in the constructor, set the private field, not the property.
In this way, you never execute the setter of a virtual property inside de constructor, which it´s the reason of the warning.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off warnings in generated code in Visual Studio projects using a checkbox in the Code Analysis property page:

> The Suppress results from generated code check box on the Code
>   Analysis property page of a project enables you to select whether you
>   want to see Code Analysis warnings from code generated by a
>   third-party tool. -  [How to: Suppress Code Analysis Warnings for Generated Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/how-to-suppress-code-analysis-warnings-for-generated-code)